# Upload video to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, amazon-ec2, video-processing

I have react-native application which after video recording need to upload it on express server which is on aws-ec2.It takes too long video uploading, how I can optimize that, which technologies or tools I need to use? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the react-native-camera library to record your video.

In recordAsync method, you can set lower quality for reducing the video size.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md#recordasyncoptions-promise